# How can I shift columns based on certain row?

Tags: python, pandas

My datatable is below.

|  | menu_nm | dtl | rcp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | sandwich | amazing sandwich!!! | bread 10g |
| 1 | hamburger | bread 20g, vegetable 10g | ??? |
| 2 | salad | fresh salad!!! | apple sauce 10g, banana 40g, cucumber 5g |
| 3 | juice | sweet juice!! | orange 50g, water 100ml |
| 4 | fruits | strawberry 10g, grape 20g, melon 10g | ??? |

and I want to get this datatable

|  | menu_nm | dtl | rcp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | sandwich | amazing sandwich!!! | bread 10g |
| 1 | hamburger |  | bread 20g, vegetable 10g |
| 2 | salad | fresh salad!!! | apple sauce 10g, banana 40g, cucumber 5g |
| 3 | juice | sweet juice!! | orange 50g, water 100ml |
| 4 | fruits |  | strawberry 10g, grape 20g, melon 10g |

I want to shift row 1, 4 to rcp column, but I can't find method or logic that I try.
I just know that shifting all row and all column, I don't know how I can shift certain row and column.

If you know hint or answer, please tell me. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access index location using .iloc as below:

```
>>> df=pd.DataFrame({"COLA":[1,2,3,4], "COLB":[100,200,300,400], "COLC":[1000,2000,3000,4000]})
>>> df
   COLA  COLB  COLC
0     1   100  1000
1     2   200  2000
2     3   300  3000
3     4   400  4000
>>> df['COLC'].iloc[1]=df['COLB'].iloc[1]
>>> df
   COLA  COLB  COLC
0     1   100  1000
1     2   200   200
2     3   300  3000
3     4   400  4000
>>> df['COLB'].iloc[1]=''
>>> df
   COLA COLB  COLC
0     1  100  1000
1     2        200
2     3  300  3000
3     4  400  4000
```

Follow similar steps for row 4.

Answer (score 1):

**assumption:** rcp column contains "???" that needs to be replaced with the a values from dtl

```
# create a filter where value under rcp is "???"
m=df['rcp'].eq('???')

# using loc, shift the values

df.loc[m, 'rcp'] =  df['dtl']
df.loc[m, 'dtl'] =  ""
df
```

```
    menu_nm     dtl                     rcp
0   sandwich    amazing sandwich!!!     bread 10g
1   hamburger                           bread 20g, vegetable 10g
2   salad       fresh salad!!!          apple sauce 10g, banana 40g, cucumber 5g
3   juice       sweet juice!!           orange 50g, water 100ml
4   fruits                              strawberry 10g, grape 20g, melon 10g
```

Comment: I tried this to another dataframe, but I found error message duplicate index.

Comment: can you provide the sample data where it failed?

Comment: My data has 8000 rows so It's hard to provide this but I can provide specific error message : ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels.
I searched this error so I did this code my column
df['column2'].is_unique 
print(df)

....Result of print is False, I found that if datas of column is False I can't use the code that ' df.loc[m, 'column2'] = df['column1']

So I tried to search that error. thanks.

Comment: Hey I found that the answer about this problem. I can solve that I tried reset index. thank you